# Как сделать так, чтобы при неправильном ответе скрипт не выходил из цикла?

Tags: bash, sh

Я хочу автоматизировать процессы. Код отслеживает папки в папке **dir1**, и количество папок может менятся. В зависимости от этого должен меняться и выбор в *вопросе*.

Но мне не хочется делать так:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export PATH_FOLDER=$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)/dir1

folders_list=($(ls ${PATH_FOLDER}))

select opt in "${folders_list[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in
            1) ITEM=${folders_list[$REPLY-1]} ;break ;;
            2) ITEM=${folders_list[$REPLY-1]} ;break ;;
            3) ITEM=${folders_list[$REPLY-1]} ;break ;;
            *) echo "такого нету" >&2
    esac
done

echo $ITEM
```

И я сделал так:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export PATH_FOLDER=$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)/dir1

folders_list=($(ls ${PATH_FOLDER}))

select opt in "${folders_list[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in
        $REPLY) ITEM=${folders_list[$REPLY-1]} ;break ;;
        *) echo "такого нету" >&2
    esac
done

echo $ITEM
```

Но почему-то при неверном ответе скрипт вылетает. Что делать?

Comment: а он и не должен по идее, `break` же на `*)` ветке нет

Comment: @user7860670  в переменной `folders_list`  больше чем один обект может по этому

Comment: вообще мне кажется что вы тут просто всегда в ветку `$REPLY)` попадаете...

Comment: какой-то странный код... что именно ты пытаешься проверить в `case`?

Comment: @Fat-Ze добавил более подробное описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подразумевая, что вопрос про то, как при использовании `select`'а обработать неправильный ввод, это можно сделать как-то так:

```
select opt in "${folders_list[@]}"; do
    if [ -n "$opt" ]; then
        ITEM="$opt"
        break
    else
        echo "«$REPLY» не является номером элемента в списке"
    fi
done
```

В случае неправильного ввода `select` присваивает `opt` пустую строку, а в случае корректного — выбранное значение из списка.